Правильное копирование содержимого папки (вложенные папки и файлы) с помощью команды xcopy
Мне периодически надо копировать на устройство содержимое папки(подпапки и файлы). Устройство подключается к ПК (Windows 11) по usb в режиме диска (не используется MTP). Я для удобства сделал bat файл с командой:
xcopy E:\dist\ G:\ /e /y

Проблема в том, что при копировании происходит что-то странное и прошивка устройства перестает запускаться. Как будто при копировании затрагиваются сторонние файлы и папки на диске устройства. При ручном копировании никаких проблем нет.
Я ради интереса пробовал делать копирование с помощью этой команды не в корень диска, а в отдельную папку:
xcopy E:\dist\ G:\dist\ /e /y

Если вручную скопировать все содержимое этой папки в корень диска устройства, то будет все корректно.
То есть проблема появляется только при копировании содержимого папки с помощью xcopy в корень диска устройства.
При этом если после xcopy вручную скопировать содержимое папки в корень диска устройства, то это не исправит ситуацию. После xcopy приходится делать восстановление всех папок/файлов устройства из бэкапа.
Пока у меня только одно предположение, что команда xcopy меняет права на папки.
Прошу помощи.

Что такое "устройство"? Что такое "подключается к ПК (Windows 11) по usb в режиме диска (не используется MTP)"? Что такое "ручное копирование"?

Устройство в данном случае можно опустить. Просто micro sd, которая подключается через card reader.  Под ручным копированием я подразумевал копирование папок/файлов с помощью стандартного проводника windows.

Раз можно опустить, тогда ждите у моря погоды. На карты microSD файлы копируются обычным образом. Нет там никаких прошивок и чудес. Дизлайк - за формулировку вопроса.

Это вам дизлайк за запрос информации, которая к вопросу вообще отношения не имеет. Какая разница, в каком устройстве я использую этот накопитель? В моем случае без разницы, как будет подключаться накопитель. Что напрямую через card reader, что через устройство, для которого используется этот накопитель.

@Echo off

REM === Папка источник (что копировать)
set BASE=D:\MyBase

REM === Папка назначение (куда?)
set OUTPUT=D:\MyOut

@echo.
@echo.
@echo.  Copy %BASE% to %OUTPUT%
@echo.  Continue ?
@echo.
@echo.  Break CTRL+C
@echo.
pause
cls

XCopy %BASE% %OUTPUT% /Y /C /I /E /R /G /H /K

cls
@echo.
@echo.
@echo.  Done!
@echo.
pause


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Откройте Блокнот (Notepad) cкопируйте код, измените пути и сохраните файл как BAT или CMD. Если не сохраняется как BAT/CMD - при сохранении нужно взять в кавычки.

Это сработало. Я просто скопировал ваши ключи в свой код. Большое спасибо. Буду благодарен если поясните, что приводит к ошибке в моем примере.

@anbarafors для правки ответа нажмите [edit]

Я не могу сказть, что не сработало, но мне кажется, что ключи. Вы видите - у меня столько ключей, а у вас всего два. Потом. Некоторые версии XCopy разные. Хотя это слишком далеко представьте для Windows 98 не сработает - лишние ключи. Читайте по справке: CMD XCopy /?
